# Tabulate Python

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

```
from tabulate import tabulate

data = {
    'Clients': ['Vini'],
    'Foods' : ['Coca'],
    'Drinks' : ['Pitu']
}

data['Clients'] = input('Digite: ')

print(tabulate(data, headers='keys', tablefmt='pretty'))
```

To com uma dúvida nesse dict, queria adicionar elementos ai com o input, mas quando eu tento, lembre fica printado caractere por caractere um abaixo do outro, e não em linha, alguém tem como ajudar ai? se tiver como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve trocar `data['Clients'] = input('Digite: ')` por `data['Clients'].append(input('Digite: '))` , deste modo você adicionará um cliente novo e não vai pular linha

Código com o while True:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

data = {
    'Clients': ['Vini'],
    'Foods' : ['Coca'],
    'Drinks' : ['Pitu']
}

while (True):
    data['Clients'].append(input('Digite: '))
    print(tabulate(data, headers='keys', tablefmt='pretty'))
```

Comment: Valeu Natan, mas uma duvida, teria como eu manter os elementos ? por exemplo, coloquei esse bloco de código num while True, e queria que cada elemento adicionado continuasse armazenado lá, porém o .append somente substitui.. tem algum método que possibilite fazer isso? se não ficou muito explicado me avise que eu tento mandar a ideia aq

Comment: Provavelmente você colocou o `data = { ...` dentro do while também, ou seja, sempre que colocar uma coisa nova, ele volta pro estado original. Editei minha resposta colocando o while True

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Show, deu certo aqui, consegui armazenar os dados no while True